# mule facebook - flow variable

Tags: facebook, mule, mule-flow

I have a mule flow with facebook connector(authorize); Before calling it I try to set some flow and session variables; When facebook authorize returns back to flow - these previously set variables do not present in flow and session anymore.

Why is it so and how can I make my variables stay in message after facebook authorize?

Comment: Please add your flow config to the post.

Comment: Config won' help. I investigated and found out that this is expected behaviour. But, there's workaround - 'State' field will preserve whatever you put there, so we can use 'State' to store thing that are needed after Facebook Authorize call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6847

Also the fact that http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/CLDCONNECT-185 has been closed `Unresolved` with a `Usage Issue` status makes me wonder if doing anything but crafting an HTTP response in the flow that contains `<facebook:authorize />` is actually discouraged.

You may want to upvote/watch/comment/re-open these issues if you think you have a strong case for it.